# Quiero mejorar el código, si es posible y esta escrito en sh o Bash

Tags: bash, vim, wget

en la pregunta anterior les pedí que me ayuden a mejorar mi código pero dijeron que no entendían como estaba hecho, entonces aquí les dejo esa parte del código completa, para que me ayuden a mejorarlo de alguna forma.

```
#!/bin/sh

temp_files(){
   local group="prueba"
   local user="prueba"
   local tmp_dir='/tmp/current_program'
   local latest="latest.tar.gz"
   local current_program_command="${tmp_dir}/get_current_program"
   local current_program_install="${tmp_dir}/install_current_program"
   local version="grep '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]'* ${tmp_dir}/version"

   mkdir ${tmp_dir} && chown ${user}:${group} ${tmp_dir}/${name}
    
    echo -e '#/bin/sh
get_current_program(){
   local name="current_program"
   local user="prueba"
   local latest="latest.tar.gz"
   local tmp_dir="/tmp/current_program"
   local current_program_url=""
   local wget_current_program="wget -P ${tmp_dir} ${current_program_url}/${name}-${latest}"
   local version="$(grep '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]'* ${tmp_dir}/version)"
   local wget_signature="wget -P ${tmp_dir} ${current_program_url}/${name}-${version}.tar.gz.sig"
   
#   ${wget_current_program} 

   tar -tf ${tmp_dir}/${name}-${latest} | grep version | cat > ${tmp_dir}/1 && tr -d 'gnuhealtvrsio/-' < ${tmp_dir}/1 > ${tmp_dir}/2 | tail -n +2 ${tmp_dir}/2 > ${tmp_dir}/version
   
#   ${wget_signature}

}

get_current_program' | cat > ${current_program_command}

   echo -e '#/bin/sh

message(){

   local UTC="$(date -u +'%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')"

   case $1 in
      ERROR ) echo -e "\n\e[1;31m${utc} [ERROR] $2\e[m";;
      WARNING ) echo -e "\n\e[1;35m${utc} [ADVERTENCIA] $2\e[m";;
      INFO ) echo -e "\n\e[1;33m${utc} [INFO] $2\e[m";;
   esac

}

install_current_program(){
   local name="current_program"
   local user="prueba"
   local latest="latest.tar.gz"
   local tmp_dir="/tmp/current_program"
   local version="$(grep '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]'* ${tmp_dir}/version)"


   # Firma incorrecta
#   local signature="gpg --verify ${tmp_dir}/${name}-2.0.4.tar.gz.sig ${tmp_dir}/${name}-${latest}"

    # Firma correcta
#   local signature="gpg --verify ${tmp_dir}/${name}-${version}.tar.gz.sig ${tmp_dir}/${name}-${latest}"

   ${signature}

   if [ $? -eq 0 ]

   then

      tar -xvf ${tmp_dir}/${name}-${latest} -C /home/${user}

      message "INFO" "La firma proporcionada es correcta, se procederÃ¡ a la descompresiÃ³n"

   else

      message "ERROR" "La firma proporcionada es incorrecta, el archivo no serÃ¡ descomprimido"

   fi

}

install_current_program' | cat > ${current_program_install}

   chown -R :${group} ${tmp_dir}
   chmod +x ${current_program_command} ${current_program_install}

   ${current_program_command}
   ${current_program_install}


}

temp_files
```

Como pueden ver las descargas están comentadas, así como las firmas en link que les envio está el `tar.gz` y las dos firmas una incorrecta y una correcta para que hagan la prueba y me ayuden a ver si puedo mejorar el código en algo, y como lo dije antes el código `SI` funciona.
Link de los archivos: https://mega.nz/folder/z7ggXBCY#huv6dpoecI0LHaKqM1aXgw

Gracias...

Comment: si sabes que para revisiones de código existe otra página?

Comment: PAra revisiones de codigo esta [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) aca solucionamos problemas, pero no revisamos codigo ya que eso lleva a preguntas basadas en opiniones....